# How to generate report (for example html report) using a different language aside from English in OWASP ZAP?

Tags: owasp, zap

I am supposed to generate a html report with a specific language (aside from English) but I could not find a solution how to change it. It's my first time to use OWASP ZAP.

I tried changing it's language (for example 日本語) and restart the application but the generated report is still in English.

Answer (score 1):

The text used in the ZAP alerts is generated when they are found, rather than when the report is generated.
So you will need to:

1. Change the language in the ZAP desktop
2. Restart ZAP (the language cannot be applied dynamically I'm afraid)
3. Perform a ZAP scan
4. Generate the report

How much of the text will be translated will depend on the language - some languages have been translated more than others.

All of the translations have been provided by the community - anyone can help out via https://crowdin.com/project/owasp-zap